# Ocaml - This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Why is the following code giving me that error?
Note that the is_sorted function returns either true or false
and make_move function returns a list of lists. e.g [[0,1,3,2],[1,0,2,3]]

```
let rec solve_helper b pos n r fn =
    if n = 0 then b :: r :: fn (*fn is the final array with all paths*)
    else match pos with
        [] -> fn
       |(h::t) -> if is_sorted h = true then h
        else h :: r (* ERROR HERE: r is the temp array that contains 1 path*)
             solve_helper  b (make_moves h) (n-1) r
             solve_helper b t (n-1) r (*tail recursion*)
;;

let solve_board b n = solver_helper b (make_moves b) n [] []
;;
```

new code:

```
let rec solve_helper b pos n r fn =
    if n = 0 then r :: fn (*fn is the final array with all paths*)
    else match pos with
        [] -> fn
       |(h::t) -> if is_sorted h = true then 
            let j = h :: r in
            r :: fn
        else
            let u = h :: r in
            let  k = solve_helper b (make_moves h) (n - 1) r fn in
            solve_helper b t (n - 1) r fn(*tail recursion*)
;;

let solve_board b n = solve_helper b (make_moves b) n [] []
;;
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines of your code:

```
    else h :: r (* ERROR HERE: r is the temp array that contains 1 path*)
         solve_helper  b (make_moves h) (n-1) r
         solve_helper b t (n-1) r (*tail recursion*)
```

do not make sense as far as I can tell. They represent a call to a function named `r` with 10 arguments (two of which are the function `r` itself).

Possibly you need to edit your code to show exactly what the compiler is seeing.

If your code actually looks like this, you need to rethink this part. It reads like imperative code (a series of things to do) rather than functional code (an expression consisting of functions applied to arguments).

Comment: I updated the code since it did not reflect the algorithm I intended to implement. The first recursive function takes care of head elements. While the second takes care of tail elements which was found using the first. They are both needed for this particular function.

Comment: Also is there a way to do h :: r without typing let j = h :: r in.

Comment: The new code makes only marginally more sense, I'm sorry to say. Maybe you should work on smaller examples until functional style starts to become clearer. For example, it doesn't make much sense to say `let j = h :: r in r :: fn`. Since you don't use `j`, there's no need to define it. This definition of `j` has no effect on `h` or `r`. Similar to the way `1 + 2` has no effect on 1 or 2.

Comment: Yeah I started learning ocaml very recently and it has been a confusing language style for me. I did let j = h :: r to get rid of an error.